# Enlarging an image without blurring by taking one pixel and turning it into four on a new image with different dimensions

Tags: c#, image, system.drawing, lockbits

I have previously written an image enlarger algorithm that enlarges images without blurring by doubling the image size and making a single pixel into four pixels on the new image. This was originally built for 500x500 pixel images and it worked absolutely fine but now I need to use it for an image that has a different width and height.

I have tried changing the values but I cannot get it to work and there maybe something missing but I don't know. Can someone help fix this so it works with different dimensions? It was built to enlarge 500x500 pixel images but the image I need to enlarge is 634x490 pixels.

The original code that works with 500x500 is below and this will work if you paste it into a project and run it but you must supply a 500x500 pixel image to it:

```
        Bitmap oldImg = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"NameOfImageToEnlarge.png"));
        Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);

        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data = oldImg.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, oldImg.PixelFormat);
        oldImg.UnlockBits(data);
        byte[] rgba = new byte[data.Stride * 500];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, rgba, 0, data.Stride * 500);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImg))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 500; y++)
                {
                    newImg.SetPixel(x * 2, y * 2, Color.FromArgb(oldImg.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb()));
                    newImg.SetPixel(x * 2 + 1, y * 2, Color.FromArgb(oldImg.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb()));
                    newImg.SetPixel(x * 2, y * 2 + 1, Color.FromArgb(oldImg.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb()));
                    newImg.SetPixel(x * 2 + 1, y * 2 + 1, Color.FromArgb(oldImg.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb()));
                }
            }
            newImg.Save(@"NameOfImageToSave.png");
        }
```

I also used some help to get the code above to work so I may have explained it more here: [Taking pixels from one image and enlarging them on a new image to create a larger version of original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386242/taking-pixels-from-one-image-and-enlarging-them-on-a-new-image-to-create-a-large)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this. The approach you're using is called "Nearest Neighbour" interpolation; you can set this property and then call `DrawImage` and you're all set:

```
using(Bitmap source = ...)
using(Bitmap destination = new Bitmap(1000, 1000))
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImg)) {

    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    g.DrawImage( source, new Rectangle( 0, 0, destination.Width, destination.Height ) );
}
```

Also, if you're using `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` there is no need to use `LockBits`. In fact, in your example you call `LockBits` and then immediately call `UnlockBits`, but still read from the `BitmapData`'s pointer, that is dangerous and may result in data-corruption if the GC moves memory around while your code is executing.

Comment: Thank you! Much shorter code that sounds better for memory and all I have to do is change the width and height of the image to output, simple, thanks again.